# How to aggregate documents in different buckets and then apply filters to the result

Tags: elasticsearch

I have many elasticsearch documents in this format:

```js
{
    "_index": "testIndex",
    "_type": "_doc",
    "_id": "0kt102sBt5sWDQMwsMNJ",
    "_score": 1.4376891,
    "_source": {
        "id": "8dJs76YI",
        "entity": "movie",
        "actor": "Pier",
        "action": "like",
        "source": "tablet",
        "tag": [
            "drama"
        ],
        "location": "3.698492,-73.697308",
        "country": "",
        "city": "",
        "timestamp": "2019-07-04T05:35:01Z"
    }
}
```

This index stores all the activities done against a `movie` entity. `id` is the `movie` id. `action` can be `like`, `view`, `share` etc. `actor` is the name of user.

I want to apply aggregation and get those movies which are having total likes between 1000 and 10000 and also liked by `actor` Pier but only those having `tags` as comedy.

The query need to have a combination of bool, terms and range query along with aggregations. I have tried filters aggregation but the official documentation example is not proving to be enough.

Can any one please give some example to prepare the query for this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

So I'd begin writing query with data that isn't part of aggregation, which is `actor` and `tag`.

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "filter": [
                {
                    "term": {
                        "actor": "Pier"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "term": {
                        "tag": "comedy"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "term": {
                        "action": "like"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

This should filter only liked `movies` where `Pier` was part of the cast and it was of `comedy` genre.

The next thing is aggregating and getting counts per movie, so it certainly makes sense to use `terms` aggregation to group everything by `id`.

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "filter": [
                {
                    "term": {
                        "actor": "Pier"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "term": {
                        "tag": "comedy"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "term": {
                        "action": "like"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    "aggs": {
        "movies": {
            "terms": {
                "field": "id",
                "min_doc_count": 1000
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So with this query you should already have counts per movie, given that we already have filtered out, these counts are for liked comedy movies where Pier has been part of cast, now this has to filter each filter to ensure wanted amount of likes.

So now it's needed to add max likes per movie. You'll need to use bucket selector for that:

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "filter": [
                {
                    "term": {
                        "actor": "Pier"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "term": {
                        "tag": "comedy"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "term": {
                        "action": "like"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    "aggs": {
        "movieIds": {
            "terms": {
                "field": "id",
                "min_doc_count": 1000
            },
            "aggs": {
                "likesWithinRange": {
                    "bucket_selector": {
                        "buckets_path": {
                            "doc_count": "_count"
                        },
                        "script": {
                            "inline": "params.doc_count < 10000"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Hopefully that works or at least puts you on a right direction.

Comment: Unfortunately this is not working. The 1st query is returning 6 docs which is fine. Now Let me explain you the scenario. ES index have data of only 1000 movies only so technically the 2nd query must return 0 documents because I have some documents which have `view` and 'share` action also but it is returning 6 documents which is equal to 1st query. The 3rd query is also returning 6 documents.

My use case is that I want to get all those movies of comedy genre which are `liked` by Pier but also liked by other users and having total number of likes above 1000 and below 10000.

Comment: Actually I want to display a list of movies **Pier** might also like based on the fact that others have also liked the same genre (**comedy**) movie but the threshold is at least 1000 likes and at most 10000 likes for those movies. I hope I am making myself a bit more clear here.

Comment: The 1st term level query is restricting the ES to return only those docs which are having Pier in the actor field. But instead it should consider other users who has liked comedy movies as well. In my opinion the `actor` filter should be applied at the very last stage after all the aggregations have been computed.

Comment: Perhaps you want to try it yourself? You now need to adjust where filters are applied. 